# skimage hog returns no feature vector with length 0

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, feature-extraction, histogram-of-oriented-gradients

I am trying to extract hog descriptors for some ROI on a given image (2D) using the implementation in skimage.feature. I have attached some samples of the ROI that I have extracted. I am just using the hog descriptor with all the default values.

Configuration: python:3.9.13; scikit-image: 0.19.2; Windows 10

The feature vector that is returned has nothing i.e. it is a null array ([]).

NOTE: I want to use the HOG descriptors from positive and negative sample to train and Linear SVM model.

*Sample ROI*
[positive sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYUzz.jpg)
[negative sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti5IX.jpg)

*Code to reproduce problem*

```
from skimage.feature import hog
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread(<path to image>, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
desc = hog(img)
print(desc)

#output: array([], dtype=float64)
```

The feature descriptor should not be null. Even if I am giving a completely blank white image there should be a descriptor. But again I am not getting a descriptor for the positive samples as well.

Can someone please help with what is going wrong or is it an issue with the implementation?

Comment: Actually I just checked that you can apply the hog on the images that I have attached after reading it using opencv imread in grayscale mode and reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is really surprising. To me this looks like a bug. If the input is too small for the operation, it should error out, not produce an empty array. I’ll have to check the source code to understand what is going on.

Comment: I've submitted an issue to the skimage project: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/7064#issue-1803707400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I referenced [the source code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/76dd2dab856f95e5264f50e376f9f3a81a261287/skimage/feature/_hog.py#L277)

It looks like it produces output for `n_blocks_row`x`n_blocks_col` elements, with:

```py
s_row, s_col = image.shape[:2]
c_row, c_col = pixels_per_cell  # input parameter, 8x8 by default
b_row, b_col = cells_per_block  # input parameter, 3x3 by default

n_cells_row = int(s_row // c_row)  # number of cells along row-axis
n_cells_col = int(s_col // c_col)  # number of cells along col-axis

n_blocks_row = (n_cells_row - b_row) + 1
n_blocks_col = (n_cells_col - b_col) + 1
```

With the image having only 16 rows, you get two cells vertically, which is not enough to fill a single block of 3x3 cells. So, `n_blocks_row` is 0, and you get as output a 0x22 array of blocks.

For such small images, you must change the `pixels_per_cell` and/or the `cells_per_block` parameters so that `pixels_per_cell[0] * cells_per_block[0]` is not larger than your image height (and similarly for the image width).

For example, this worked for me:

```py
skimage.feature.hog(img, cells_per_block=(2,2))
```

though I don't know if this produces a useful output or not. Having fewer cells per block might not give you as good a result. Maybe you could make the blocks wider as you make them less tall, so their size remains the same? Something like `cells_per_block=(2,5)`? I don't have enough experience with HOG to advice on this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. An exception should have been raised. As for the "cells_per_block = (2,5)" for sure it can be done (main reason being it is allowed). Also in HOG these are just aggregating information upwards (in order) pixel -> cell -> block -> histogram and then other steps follow.