# OpenCV HOGDescriptor() throws error vector<T> is too long

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction, histogram-of-oriented-gradients

I am trying to extract hog descriptors for some ROI on a given image (2D) using the implementation in OpenCV. I have attached some samples of the ROI that I have extracted. I am just using the hog descriptor with all the default values.

Configuration: python:3.9.13; opencv-python 4.7.0; Windows 10

An error is thrown as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: vector<T> too long
```

NOTE: I want to use the HOG descriptors from positive and negative sample to train and Linear SVM model.

Sample ROI [positive sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byQEX.jpg) [negative sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY8oH.jpg)

*Code to reproduce problem*

```
import cv2 as cv
hog = cv.HOGDescriptor()
img = cv.imread(<path to image>, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
desc = hog.compute(img)
```

I do understand that there is a limit on vector size but the image size is really not that big which is 193 X 16 (width X height)

Is there a workaround to this problem or am I messing up somewhere?

Comment: The error message made me think you’re trying C++ now. :)

Comment: It is likely that OpenCV's HOG descriptor is failing for [the same reason as skimage's is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76682937/7328782) (but in a less graceful way): your blocks are too large for the image.

Comment: However, here the vector size is exceeding the limit. Its not an empty vector if we try to find the analogy with the skimage issue.

Comment: I submitted an issue to the OpenCV project as well: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/23989

Comment: The error message you see is something internally going wrong because the code is not expecting to produce a zero-size output. It is internal because it references a C++ type, OpenCV typically doesn't do that if it gets the wrong input. -- If you make the input larger, it doesn't error out. I guess you can change the block size like in skimage, but I didn't bother figuring out how to do that.

Comment: Yea no problem. I can work on it now that I know what's the root cause.

Comment: @CrisLuengo should I delete this question or just let it be?

Comment: Feel free to leave it open. If you have a workaround you can post it as an answer.